# Multiplying Gaussians of different dimensions

Tags: probability

Let $G_1(x, \mu_1, \sigma_1)$ be a 1D Gaussian and $G_2(x, y, \mu_2, \mu_2, \sigma_2)$ be a 2D Gaussian.

What is the product of theses two Gaussians:
$$
G(x, y) = G_1(x, \mu_1, \sigma_1) G_2(x, y, \mu_2, \mu_2, \sigma_2)
$$
I want to find a mean and covariance of the product.

I have tried to write $G_1$ as a degenerate 2D Gaussian with inverse covariance 
matrix $\Sigma_1^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} & 0 \\
0 & 0  \end{array} \right)
$
and then use standard multiplication rule to get new mean and variance.
But $\Sigma_1$ is singular and can't invert it.

Any suggestions how to approach this?

Comment: I suppose you mean you are multiplying a Gaussian random variable with a bivariate Gaussian random vector. Under this context, when I scalar is multiplied with a vector, I assume it is simply a scalar multiplication and returns a vector. The question is you need to clarify the parameters in the bivariate normal (one variance and the covariances), and are the $X$ be the same random variable; if not, are they mutually independent.